# Shrinking Schauder Basis for a Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, book-recommendation, schauder-basis

Let $E$ be a Banach space with a Schauder basis. Let $S_n$ be the operator of partial sum. We say that the Schauder basis is shrinking if for every $f \in E^*$ we have $f○S_n \rightarrow f$ in the norm topology of $E^*$ .

Where can such definition be found ?

Comment: I would suggest Megginson's *An Introduction to Banach Space Theory* (or any text discussing bases in depth), or [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975644?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it in

Ivan Singer: Bases in Banach Spaces I (Springer)

Chapter II, § 4: k - shrinking bases.